# Creating a VSCode Webview in a Tabbed Panel?

Tags: vscode-extensions

I have been going through the documentation but I am not understanding. When I create a webview like this:

```
const panel = window.createWebviewPanel('hello', 'Hello', vscode.ViewColumn.One, {
      ...
    });
```

It creates a new webview in the "One" column. I can move it to different columns but these columns are not the same as tabs you find at the bottom of VSCode. I would like to create a webview and place it in one of these tabs.

[image: tabs]

One of the problems is I just don't know what this thing is called. Are these also considered webviews?

Answer (score 2):

From what I know you cannot add more tabs to this area and those that exist are built internally, so I see no way to add a web view there.

The only two locations I know of for web views are: the editor (group) tab and sidebar views.

However, if you can find an extension that adds a new tab there then check its source code to see how it does it.

Comment: Thanks maybe that's why I kept coming up dry no matter what search term I used. I don't have an example of such an extension. I just assumed it would be possible. It even lacks "contributors" from what I can tell.